# Error on redux suddenly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a strange error for couple of hours and really couldn't figure out what it is. The app was working fine and then after I've changed the name of a page headline gave me this error.

TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'todo._id')

This error is located at:

```
in TodoList (created by Connect(TodoList))
in Connect(TodoList) (at NavigatorIOS.ios.js:862)
in RCTNavItem (at NavigatorIOS.ios.js:854)
in StaticContainer (at NavigatorIOS.ios.js:853)
in RCTNavigator (at NavigatorIOS.ios.js:52)
in NavigatorTransitionerIOS (at NavigatorIOS.ios.js:882)
in StaticContainer (at NavigatorIOS.ios.js:881)
in RCTView (at View.js:78)
in View (at NavigatorIOS.ios.js:917)
in NavigatorIOS (at Main.js:26)
in Main (at App.js:25)
in RCTView (at View.js:78)
in View (at App.js:34)
in App (created by Connect(App))
in Connect(App) (at App.js:12)
in Provider (at App.js:11)
in todoListAuth (at registerRootComponent.js:35)
in RootErrorBoundary (at registerRootComponent.js:34)
in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:35)
in RCTView (at View.js:78)
in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
in RCTView (at View.js:78)
in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
```

- app/components/TodoList.js:74:30 in
- app/components/TodoList.js:72:34 in renderTodos
- app/components/TodoList.js:99:11 in TodoList_render
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:8707:21 in finishClassComponent
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:11771:25 in performUnitOfWork
- ... 22 more stack frames from framework internals

Since that time I've tried to fix it somehow even to get a repo from yesterday but same thing without changing everything. Is that something with redux package?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Code I've changed

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.topBar}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onBack}>
        <Icon name="chevron-left" size={20} color="white"/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Text style={styles.title}>
        New To-Do // This is the text I've changed
      </Text>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.addNewTodo}>
        <Icon name="check" size={20} color="white"/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
```

Error lines

```
var renderTodos = () => {
  return this.props.todos.map((todo) => { // Line 72
    return (
      <TodoItem key={todo._id} text={todo.text} id={todo._id}/> // Line 74
    )
  })
}
{renderTodos()} // Line 99
```

Comment: can you share code snippet what you have changed, either todo is null or _id is null that is causing that error

Comment: @NagaSaiA please see my edit

Comment: Can you show the code that runs `todo._id`, where the error is being thrown?

Comment: @RoryO'Kane I just updated my post with the lines are thrown the error

Comment: can you try to console todo inside .map , just to make sure todo and todo._id is available

Comment: I can't console log because the app stops right after build it

Comment: The error says it all. Somehow in the expression `todo._id`, `todo` is null. Since `todo` comes from an element in `this.props.todos`, that must mean the array contains values which are set to `null`. You'll want to debug what the value of that prop is and what is passing it in that way.

Comment: @Jacob so I've putted `<TodoItem key={'todo._id'} text={'todo.text'} id={'todo._id'}/>` and console log `this.props.todos` and returned an array with multiple elements I've created before

Comment: Are you sure _all_ values in the array are not null? The error is definitely saying that in at least one iteration of the loop, `todo` is set to `null`.

Comment: @Jacob All values has a different id